# Error: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter, but class was expected

Tags: java, hadoop

I've tried to run Coordinate Descent Tensor Factorization(CDTF) via Hadoop 2.7.2

The CDTF src code can get this page: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kijungs/codes/cdtf/

When I run CDTF mr(MapReduce) version algorithm, I get the error in step `Start Bias-CDTF`

I really don't know why the error occurs.

Is there a good solution to solve this error?

Answer (score 4):

You have an issue with versions of dependencies, one of the libraries that expects `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter` to be a `class` was most probably compiled against old version of Apache Hadoop, e.g.

- version 2.4.1 defines interface https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html
- version 1.2.1 defines class https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html

You should either update the version of library that expects `Counter` to be a `class` (most probably there is a newer version that already support version Hadoop 2.* and works with `interface`), or if this is not possible - downgrade your dependencies and use version 1.* of Apache Hadoop library

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I'll try it!

Comment: I downloaded `hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz` And I wanna to replace the current jar file with the 1.2.1 jar file, but I don't know which jar file to replace. Is it `hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar`?